# Ansible django permission denied

Tags: ansible

Here is the vars

```
pythonpath: /usr/lib/python2.7
path: /srv/trydjango/
```

Here is the deploy.yml

```
- name: django migrate
  django_manage: command=migrate app_path={{ install_root }}/{{ project_name }} pythonpath={{ pythonpath }}
```

Getting 
`fatal: [138.197.93.219]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "./manage.py migrate --noinput --pythonpath=/usr/lib/python2.7", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 13] Permission denied", "rc": 13}`

Answer (score 2):

It's an Ansible bug.

This happen under Vagrant, due to `manage.py` do not have executive permission. I had tried open ticket https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15443

ps. As temporary solution, you can try mount vagrant share folder with executive flag, as

```
config.vm.synced_folder "....",
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "vagrant",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=764"]
```